# Как добавить вью вниз layout, расположенного в scrollView

Tags: android, xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"> 

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutQuestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="517dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            ЗДЕСЬ ВЬЮХи которые добавляются динамически, во время исполнения кода

            </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Button" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При добавлении вьюх в LinearLayout  кнопка должна оставиться внизу, а если вьюх много, то интерфейс должен прокручиваться, но кнопка по прежнему внизу. Как этого достичь?   Если убрать fillViewport , то остается только кнопка, которая расположится вверху экрана..

Этот xml находится  здесь, как разментка для `TabItem`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.LearnTickets.LearnTickets">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/ticket_tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/ticket_tabs1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2" />


        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кнопка всегда прилеплена к нижнему краю экрана и видна, остальное прокручивается:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutQuestion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            ЗДЕСЬ ВЬЮХи которые добавляются динамически, во время исполнения кода

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: woesss, нет, изначально, я хотел чтобы кнопка уходила за экран, если контента много, нашел кучу подобных вопросов в анг. стековерфлоу, но все варианты как один неверные, видно, что методом тыка пробовали, чего то достичь.     Знаю, что исходя из пользовательского опыта, это не лучшее решение, но вот хотелось сильно именно так реализовать.

Comment: Позже, я отказался от этой идеи и решил сделать так как вы поняли. И сделал точно так как в вашем ответе, но увы это не работает. Кнопки просто нет. Ее как, я понимаю, накрывает scrollView .  Пробовал установить android:fillViewport="true"   безуспешно

Comment: Кстати, когда linearLayout пуст даже, этой кнопки не видно.

Comment: Обновил: такой вариант должен сработать

Comment: нет, не работает, кнопки по прежнему не видно.  В студии в дизайнере всё выглядит как и предполагаем мы: почти на весь экран скролвью и ниже кнопка, но отображается кнопка, если задать вес 1 . Но на пол экрана кнопка. А если вес 0.0001 , чтобы в дизайнере всё было красиво, то в приложении кнопки снова не видно .

Comment: Да плевать на дизайнер - "Вам шашечки или ехать?". На девайсе правильно отображается? Если нет попробуйте дать кнопке вес `0`.

Comment: Нашел в чем проблема. В чистом проекте всё работает. Дело в том что я эту разметку использую для tabItem в  приложенной сейчас  разметке видно это. И как видите у меня есть  Toolbar и ровно на высоту этого Toolbar моя кнопка уходит вниз.  Как этого избежать пока не пойму

Comment: У меня раньше была такая проблема, я заменил scrollView на recyclerView и не пришлось подгонять, но в данной ситуации scrollView выглядит самым разумным вариантом.

Comment: woesss, решением было убрать это app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" из Toolbar . И вместо scrollView использовать NeastedScrollView , как это я забыл что scrollView уже устарел и некорректно работает с новыми виджетами.

Comment: Я приму ваш ответ , так как он на изначальную проблему верно отвечает. А те кто столкнулся с моей проблемой найдут инфу в комментах.